IFS function in Google sheet is not returning the correct value
In Google Sheet, cell I46 contains this formula:
= iferror(average(C46:H46), "")
And cell J46 contains this formula:
=IF(len(I46) = 0, "",
    IF(I46 >= 4.8, 150000,
       IF(AND(I46 >= 4.5, I46 < 4.8), 100000,
          IF(AND(I46 >= 4.2, I46 < 4.5), 0,
             IF(AND(I46 >= 3.9, I46 < 4.2), -100000,
                IF(I46 < 3.9, -150000, "")
             )
          )
       )
    )
 )

(this is what I got from asking chatGPT)
problem: cell I46 has the value 4.8, which should prompt 150000 in cell J46, but 100000 is showing instead -> Can anyone help me?
for context: I set the locale in the US, so the decimal separator is dot ("."). Also, I do not think there's something wrong with the format, as the same function works perfectly fine for other rows
Tried asking chatGPT, but can't give me the answer I'm looking for

Most likely the value in I46 is not 4.8 but a rounded value representation of 4.799999999 or so...

I would not use an if() for more than 3 levels, so I have shown the use of vlookup() :

VLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$B$7,2,1)

A comment points out the issue of the value to be tested, round() can be used to control that:
round(d3,1)

maybe roundup() or rundown() may be more appropriate.

Change the formula in I46 to:
= iferror(ROUND(average(C46:H46),2), "")

Your formatting is likely rounding the value to appear as 4.8, but in reality it is 4.79876432 that will not give you the result you are looking for as pointed out by rockinfreakshow. If the values are rounded, you could also avoid all the IF statements and replace it with a simpler VLOOKUP and a lookup table as suggested by Solar Mike.
